# How to clean a specific field in Django forms.Form?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a Django form like this.

```
class TransactionForm(forms.Form):
      start = forms.DateField()
      end = forms.DateField()
```

I wanted to change the value before running validation:

```
def clean_start(self):
    start = sef.cleaned_data.get('start')
    return bs_to_ad(start)   #This function returns date in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format
```

The problem is that this method runs in forms.ModelForm object but doesn't in forms.Form object.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the data before calling `__init__` method using a custom `__init__` method like this

```
class TransactionForm(forms.Form):
    start = forms.DateField()
    end = forms.DateField()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        if "data" in kwargs:
            start = kwargs.get("data").get("start")
            # modify start
            kwargs["data"]["start"] = start
        super().__init__(self, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Simply doing this works fine.

```
class TransactionFrom(forms.Form):
  start = forms.DateField()
  end = forms.DateField()
  def clean(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data
    if 'start' in data.keys():
        start = bs_to_ad(data.get('start'))
    if 'end' in data.keys():
        end = bs_to_ad(data.get('end'))
    self.cleaned_data.update({'start': start, 'end': end})
```